# Markdown tables with soucre block?

Tags: markdown

I was asked to port some documentation from AsciiDoctor to Markdown, and I have to insert source block examples in table cells... Huge tables, by the way (DB structure description).
But I cant. I tried to play with HTML for that single row, but I could not make it work.
Do you know some way of doing it?
I hope not embedding everything in the same line and inserting manual whitespaces, hehehee.
Should I use some other flavor (I'm using MkDocs)?

Thanks and cheers

Comment: While the possible duplicate I just linked to references "Java" code specifically, the answer is the same regardless of language. And the Markdown implementation used by MkDocs specifically does **not** support block level constructs inside table cells.

Comment: actually, it's possible e.g. in pandoc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35635553/214446

Comment: What flavour of Markdown? The original implementation doesn't support tables at all (unless you fall back to HTML).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally solved just with regex html code (br's and &nbsp's), hard, but a solution.
I use Mkdocs, that supports tables :)