# Building and versioning complex tables

Tags: github, markdown

I want to share a huge tables with my team (and possibly in future with public) so that the team can collaborate on it to add / modify / remove content from the table. By "huge", I mean that the table will contain a paragraph, code (and 
possibly mathematical equation with MathJax) in each cell. I want to version control these tables. So I was thinking if I can share it with say GitHub repository. But I feel that current markdown processors are [not that great at complex tables](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/). Also it seems that stackoverflow too does not have any good support for this. Is it possible to have complex table written in markdown version controlled? Any example you have ever came across? Also any better alternative (markdown flavor or altogether different technology (except Office suites since they are not that great to version control and public collaboration))?

Comment: Possibly related: [Markdown: How to insert Java code block inside table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32085498/866026)

Comment: Also possibly related: [Line break in table using GitHub flavored markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33082540/866026)

Comment: Just had a thought. I can have html `<table>` in my webpage and each table cell may have different markdown file as its source, so we have contents of each cell separately version controlled. The only pain is to deal with different markdown files belonging to different cells. However this also makes sense as I dont have to version control table structure. Also I feel this will make the whole composite document more clean and manageable, if the table turns out to contain a lot of cells. Have you came across any page doing this?

Comment: Standard Markdown does not include support for any sort of "include". Also, as a reminder, standard markdown does not process anything as Markdown inside raw HTML blocks (including tables). You would need a custom parser or one which supports extensions to do either of those things.

Comment: cant we invoke markdown parser on different `<span><span>` marked as within same page...? might not be that straight....but seems that if the markdown parser is made plugable, then this must be obvious usage approach: call js function and pass the html element containing markdown text...though I never dealt with them first hand...need to explore...